# How to acces to the query parameter

Tags: java, rest, jersey

My client would send a request corresponding to:

```
GET http://example.com/services/rs/calendar/origin/destination/outwardDate/returnDate?nbPax=&typo=&card
```

I do this:

```
  @Path("/service/rs") public class MyServiceImpl {
        public MyServiceImpl() {
            super();
        }

        @GET
       @Path("/{origin}/{destination}/{goDate}/{returnDate}")
    public Response getCalendar(@PathParam("origin") String origin, @PathParam("destination") String destination, @PathParam("goDate") String goDate, @PathParam("returnDate") String returnDate, @QueryParam("nbPax") String nbPax, @QueryParam("typo") String typo, @QueryParam("card") String card) {

    //print my parameters        
    return Response.ok("Success").build();
        }
    }
```

there cannot map my query parameter, fails with 404, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the signature of your method and add the placeholders inside the `@Path` annotation to map the path parts to those `@PathParam`-annotated arguments. The parts that are query params should use the `@QueryParam` annotation.

```
@GET
@Path("/calendar/{origin}/{destination}/{outwardDate}/{returnDate}")
public Response getInfo(@PathParam("origin") String origin,
                        @PathParam("destination") String destination, 
                        @PathParam("outwardDate") String outwardDate, 
                        @PathParam("returnDate") String returnDate,
                        @QueryParam("nbPax") String nbPax, 
                        @QueryParam("typo") String typo, 
                        @QueryParam("card")  String card) {
```

Also, be aware that if you web application is rooted at some context path (this is typical for applications deployed inside Servlet containers like Tomcat or JBoss), the context path will be part of the URL, e.g.

```
http://[server host]/[app context path]/[class' @Path]/[method's @Path]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the address

```
http://example.com/services/rs/calendar/
```

and you are calling

`http://example.com/services/rs/calendar/origin/destination/outwardDate/returnDate`

where you are treating word "origin" (and the rest) as parameter, while its actually part of address, I believe you have no REST service attached to:

```
http://example.com/services/rs/calendar/origin/destination/outwardDate/returnDate
```

Thats why you are getting 404.

Those words you are trying to pull are of type @PathParam, @QueryParam is what you have after `?` sign